# Horizontally scaling SQL Server, distributing the database with sharding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sharding, performance, distributed-databases, performance-testing

I wanted to know if there is any way to distribute a SQL Server (I'm using 2012 version) database accross multiple nodes. I'm trying to compare READ queries performance between SQL Server and MongoDB. The distribution is all set with MongoDB with different shards using virtual machines and I wanted to make a similar setting for SQL Server, but I'm facing lots of trouble.

Is there any material on how to do that? Is that as tough process as it seems?

Comment: It is easy to distribute reads, e.g. with Availability Groups. Distributing writes is a little tougher.

Comment: Distributed partitioned views (reads), dynamic data routing (reads and writes), peer to peer replication (reads and writes), Multiple different Azure options. **However** none of these are just "flip a switch" to turn on/use and will require either the application being created with specific knowledge of such things or you'll be required to create the infrastructure yourself inside of SQL Server. Nothing is built in default.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there material on how?

Yes. You can read about it at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589797.aspx

> Is the process as tough as it seems?

Sort of. It is time consuming in that it requires careful planning in advance on how you want to structure the data, but if you're doing something with a massive database, I've personally been very pleased with the performance enhancement.